# Where is MySQL stored on Amazon EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've set up an EC2 instance with LAMP stack. I'm in remote system explorer in eclipse right now, trying to find the file location of my database. Where does Amazon store the MySQL/database file?

Comment: What OS/flavor are you running? How did you install mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using mysql in EC2 instance, you can use Amazon RDS instance for mysql. It is more easy to access the database.

If you want mysql in EC2 itself, you can access through port `3306`.
eg: `jdbc:mysql//ec2-xx-xx-xx.compute.awsamazon.com:3306/dbname`